# Parsing from JSON file into Java object

Tags: java, json, web-services

**i am using the below json file**

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ssjoqalpf5sovrqt2mkbpj2t))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata#People('russellwhyte')/Trips",
    "value": [
        {
            "tripId": 0,
            "shareId": "9d9b2fa0-efbf-490e-a5e3-bac8f7d47354",
            "description": "Trip from San Francisco to New York City. Nice trip with two friends. It is a 4 days' trip. We actually had a client meeting, but we also took one to go sightseeings in New York.",
            "name": "Trip in US",
            "budget": 3000,
            "startsAt": "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "endsAt": "2014-01-04T00:00:00Z",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**But i am getting error while parsing the file...below is my java code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee employee = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        try {
            employee = mapper.readValue(new File("C:/Users/vikram.b.ravi/Desktop/trip.json"),
                    Employee.class);
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(employee);
    }
```

***The error i am getting

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (']' (code 93)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: C:\Users\vikram.b.ravi\Desktop\trip.json; line: 12, column: 14]null***
```

***Kindly help me how to suppress the special characters in the JSON file????***

Comment: Can you wrap the json text as source code (4 space indentation) to increase its readability?

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not valid.

You have to remove the comma at end of line "endsAt"
and the first `[` has to be deleted:

```
{
        "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(ssjoqalpf5sovrqt2mkbpj2t))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata#People('russellwhyte')/Trips",
        "value": [
            {
                "tripId": 0,
                "shareId": "9d9b2fa0-efbf-490e-a5e3-bac8f7d47354",
                "description": "Trip from San Francisco to New York City. Nice trip with two friends. It is a 4 days' trip. We actually had a client meeting, but we also took one to go sightseeings in New York.",
                "name": "Trip in US",
                "budget": 3000,
                "startsAt": "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "endsAt": "2014-01-04T00:00:00Z"
            }
        ]
    }
```